# Iterate through a numpy array without a for loop

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have two arrays

```
x * 2
x * 4
```

where

```
x = np.ones([5,4],int)
```

I want to create an array `U` such that

```
U = np.empty([5,2,4])
U[:,0,:] = x * 2
U[:,1,:] = x * 4
```

but I wish to do this automatically (in particular without for loops). Ideally with a one line command like

```
U[:,?,:] = x * ?
```

Is there something to substitute to `?` to make it work? It is important to avoid both to insert the objects manually and the for loops. This because this is a toy model of something much bigger. With huge numbers for loops take too much time.

Thanks.

Comment: `np.dstack([x * 2, x * 4]).swapaxes(1,2)`, with a lot of guessing about the invariants of the problem.

Comment: Anyhow, this solution implies to list all the arrays manually, which is what I want to avoid (this is a toy example for a wider problem with arrays of huge dimension)

Comment: Don't assume that anyone who commented also voted, up or down.  My guess is that downvoters in particular, don't comment and don't revisit the question.  They've expressed their opinion, and moved on to more interesting questions.  Complaints are useless.

Comment: @hpaulj: I totally agree. I didn't mean that, I just wrote "thanks" and the rest in the same message because I'm used to occupying as least space as possible.

Answer (score 1):

In `numpy` 'iteration without loops' means using compiled numpy methods to iterate in c code.  It just moves the loops to a more efficient level.

```
In [2]: x = np.ones([5,4],int)
```

Your example:

```
In [3]: U = np.empty([5,2,4])
   ...: U[:,0,:] = x * 2
   ...: U[:,1,:] = x * 4

In [4]: U
Out[4]: 
array([[[2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [4., 4., 4., 4.]],

       [[2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [4., 4., 4., 4.]],

       [[2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [4., 4., 4., 4.]],

       [[2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [4., 4., 4., 4.]],

       [[2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [4., 4., 4., 4.]]])
```

Doing the same thing with a simple broadcasted elementwise multiplication.  With the `None` I'm creating (5,1,4) and (2,1) arrays, which broadcast to (5,2,4).

```
In [5]: x[:,None,:]*np.array([2,4])[:,None]
Out[5]: 
array([[[2, 2, 2, 2],
        [4, 4, 4, 4]],

       [[2, 2, 2, 2],
        [4, 4, 4, 4]],

       [[2, 2, 2, 2],
        [4, 4, 4, 4]],

       [[2, 2, 2, 2],
        [4, 4, 4, 4]],

       [[2, 2, 2, 2],
        [4, 4, 4, 4]]])
```

Basically this requires understanding `numpy` basics, especially how the operators work with broadcasting.

A variant on @Michael's `dstack`:

```
In [7]: np.stack([x*2, x*4], axis=1).shape
Out[7]: (5, 2, 4)
```